# UIButton's titleLabel not accessible depending on context

Tags: ios

In one of my classes, I can run

```
UIButton *testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
NSLog(@"testButton's titleLabel is %@", testButton.titleLabel);
```

and it prints the titleLabel just fine:

```
2013-02-26 19:11:49.223 Facebook[82876:c07] testButton's titleLabel is <UIButtonLabel: 0x1aad39f0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1aad3a90>>
```

In a class during a test, however, I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I try to access the testButton's titleLabel, even though I'm using the same two lines of code.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are accessing a released object, either retain this object till you are using it or use ARC

Comment: It looks like it should work with both. buttonWithType returns an autoreleased UIButton, and the titelLabel property is `@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UILabel *titleLabel`

Comment: Rose `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` comes only when that object is released form the memory. Also your `titleLable` property is correct but what about `testButton` it's just a local var..